# Javascript to display sum of 50 textboxes values

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax

I have around 50 textboxes in my webpage, where user can enter numeric values. As they enter the numbers I have to display the total of all the numbers in another label.

Is there an AJAX or Javascript solution?

So can someone please help me to find what is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: What JavaScript libraries are you using? jQuery would be ideal for something like this.

Comment: I tried using OnTextChanged event handler calling a server side method and ended up refreshing the page every time..

Comment: down voter please explain why negative vote?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With jQuery

```
var total = 0;
$('input:text').each(function() {
    total = total + parseInt($(this).val());
});
```

With plain JavaScript

```
var total = 0;
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for(var i=0; i < inputs.length; i++)
{
    var input = inputs[i]
    if (input.type == 'text') {
         total = total + parseInt(input.value);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Dustin Laibe:+1 for the quick solution :)

Comment: Excellant +1; Very clean solution.

Comment: This answer is wrong, you forgot about type coercion to String. Look: http://jsfiddle.net/u3ucH/

Comment: @Dustin; One question. If I have textboxes in one table and I want to sum of that table's textbox, then what could be the jquery function ? Lets say I have many controls, but I will group some textboxes in table and want to get sum of that table controls.

Comment: You can just change the selector, `$('#tableID input:text')`

Answer (score 1):

What you would need to do is set an event listener (onkeyup maybe) on every box that calls a single function. That function iterates over all the boxes and sets the appropriate value.

http://jsfiddle.net/HqUDw/